# The code runs again no matter what.

Tags: java, bluej

I don't know why, but the below code makes the user run the code again, whether they choose to or not. I've tried many things, but it doesn't work correctly.

Thanks!

```
 public static void main (String [ ] args)
{


    boolean a = true;
    while (a)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an integer:  ");
        int x = scan.nextInt();



        System.out.print("\n\nEnter a second integer:  ");
        int z = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        binaryConvert1(x, z);



        System.out.println("\n\nWould you like to run this code again? Enter \"Y\" or \"N\".");
        System.out.print("Enter your response here:  ");

        String RUN = scan.nextLine();
        String run = RUN.toLowerCase();
        if (run.equals("n"))
        {
            a = false;
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("Goodbye.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.nextInt()` doesn't consume the line ending characters from the buffer, which is why when you read the value of the "yes/no" question with `scan.nextLine()`, you'll receive an empty string instead of the value the user entered.

A simple way to fix this is to explicitly parse the integer from raw lines using `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer:  ");
int x = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

System.out.print("\n\nEnter a second integer:  ");
int z = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
```